# How to store html tags in php variable

Tags: php, html, variables

Ok so im making a login system and for some reason when typed like this im getting issues with it posting without an echo or print and the following script the displays itself help anyone.

```
<?PHP $form = '
 <form method="POST" action="login.php">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username:<td>
        <td><input type="text" name="user"><td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:<td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password"><td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="loginbtn" value="Login"><td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="register.php">Register</a><td>
        <td><a href="forgotpass.php">Forgoten Password</a><td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>'
;
?>
```

Comment: Do you have PHP installed on your web server? If this script would be executed, nothing would happen. You just assign all the HTML to a variable, and then end the script without using that variable. If you see all the code, the script is not executed at all. How are you testing this?

Comment: What issues are you having?

Comment: As you have typed, `$form` is just a giant string.

Comment: This is really not the way you should display HTML within PHP

Comment: lack of `echo $form;` ?

Comment: Remove PHP tags, remove <?php at beginning and ?> at the end. This is HTML code so it should not be within php tags.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want a simple HTML page, then remove <?php ?> tags, or if you want PHP, then you have to `echo $form`, otherwise it will not do anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php //Some PHP Code if necessary 
if(true) { //Any html between this brace and the next brace will be included

?>

<form method="POST" action="login.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:<td><td>
            <input type="text" name="user">
            <td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:<td><td>
            <input type="password" name="password">
            <td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><td><td>
            <input type="submit" name="loginbtn" value="Login">
            <td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="register.php">Register</a><td><td><a href="forgotpass.php">Forgoten Password</a><td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
} //End of if statement.
else { //This won't be shown, because the if statement is always true
?>
<div>
    This is not displayed
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: its being used in an if statement where the else is the form so  i put it in a var

Comment: There's a much better way to do that. You can intersperse html between the php control statements and it will act as expected. For example, <?php if(true) {?> <div>This will be displayed </div> <?php } else {?> <div>This won't be displayed </div> <?php }? >